# i tried to upate my ejs page with fetch but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, ejs

i tried to build a simple app but i got a problem
my app is just some peoples data saved in the db and the target is just to display them on the screen but we can search those people by name.
i have a ejs page and javascript file connected to him

js code:

```
document.querySelector(".search__box_input").addEventListener("click", async function(event) {
    fetch("/", {
        method: "get",
        headers: new Headers({'search': searchButton.value})
    })
})
```

node code:

```
app.get("/", async(req, res) => {
    if(!req.headers["search"] || req.headers["search"] === ''.trim()) {
        return res.render("home", persons: await personSchema.find({}).limit(10)}) // personSchema is my mongoose schema
    } else {
        const foundDocuments = await personSchema.find({"name.first": req.headers["search"]})
        console.log(foundDocuments); // i got my document correctly
        if(!foundDocuments) return res.send("could'nt find the user")
        return res.render("home", {
            persons: foundDocuments // It doesn't render again
        })
    }
})
```

i want to render the ejs again..
someone can help me pls?

Comment: You are doing `fetch("/")` and then... nothing. It's like calling someone on the phone, leaving the phone on the table and then just staring at the phone. You need to process the response and do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of Ajax is that you make a request with JavaScript and the response is given back to your JavaScript to process. Typically this would involve doing a [DOM update](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents).

Your JavaScript is completely ignoring the response.

```
const response = await fetch(...);
const text = await response.text();
console.log(text);
```

If you want to render the whole page again, then don't use Ajax. Just use a regular form submission.

(And put the `search` parameter in the query string instead of a custom header).

Comment: thanks friend. got you.